# Website does not work properly when internet explorer security settings in high

Tags: javascript, c#, web

We have a website for our business partners. We sent them invitation mail to access our website. When they click our link, if they have a high setting in internet explorer security segment, they are having some problems like:

- Cannot login(Login code simply checks for the if invitation does exists in the database)
- Javascript code blocks does not run.
- Some pictures doesn't load sometimes.

We can't ask all our partners to lower their internet security settings. They have their own policy about that.

The site is aspx(c#) and some javascript validations in it. Its a simple page about gathering some infos about their works.

Do you have any ideas about this kinda problem and how to solve it from our side? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Have a look here: [Link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/steriley/2008/09/16/internet-explorer-security-levels-compared/) - there you have an oversight what is not allowed in high security mode. Keywords could be "cross domain" or "cookies" which are often used for websites...